# Moving data between oracle and sql server using Linked server

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, linked-server, loadjava

I have set up Oracle Linked server on Sql Server 2005 box using Oracle provider oledb and its working fine from sql server 2005 to oracle 9i, i.e. When i run distributed query from sql server i get data from oracle server to sql server. Now I don't have any clue how do i run distributed query from Oracle server and get data from sql server repeatedly. Do i have to set up Dsn ? What other things i have to set up before i run query from oracle server?

FYI : Oracle server is Sun solaris server and SQL server is x64 Windows Server 2003. Sql server has oracle client installed on it with odac drivers for ORACLE Provider for OLEDB.
I am going to use loadjava to load java into oracle and than move data between both repeatedly. (Java, Stored procedures & Triggers from oracle to get data from sql server)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/10893_3442661_1/Making-a-Connection-from-Oracle-to-SQL-Server.htm) is one way. [DG4ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/applications/oracle/database-gateway-dg4odbc.html) setup guide here.

[This](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=2276389) might help, too.

Answer (score 0):

linking databases is the first phase. After that you may face the problems we faced, like not being able to delete fetched rows from Sql Server to Oracle Server remotely.
I will post a question about that, it is odd that our procedures used for data synching do not respons the same.